# Shell Script, When executing commands do something if an error is returned

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to automate out a lot of our pre fs/db tasks and one thing that bugs me is not knowing whether or not a command i issue REALLY happened. I'd like a way to be able to watch for a return code of some sort from executing that command. Where if it fails to `rm` because of a permission denied or any error. to issue an `exit`..

**If i have a shell script as such:**

```
rm /oracle/$SAPSID/mirrlogA/cntrl/cntrl$SAPSID.ctl;
```

psuedo code could be something similar to..

```
rm /oracle/$SAPSID/mirrlogA/cntrl/cntrl$SAPSID.ctl;
if [returncode == 'error']
  exit;
fi
```

how could i for example, execute that rm command and exit if its NOT rm'd. I will be adapting the answer to execute with multiple other types of commands such as `sed -i -e`, and `cp` and `umount`

## edit:

Lets suppose i have a write protected file such as:

```
$ ls -lrt | grep protectedfile
-rwx------ 1 orasmq  sapsys         0 Nov 14 12:39 protectedfile
```

And running the below script generates the following error because obviously theres no permissions..

```
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file `/tmp/protectedfile'? y
rm: cannot remove `/tmp/protectedfile': Operation not permitted
```

Here is what i worked out from your guys' answers.. is this the right way to do something like this? Also how could i dump the error `rm: cannot remove` /tmp/protectedfile': Operation not permitted` to a logfile?

```
#! /bin/bash
function log(){
    //some logging code, simply writes to a file and then echo's out inpit
}
function quit(){
   read -p "Failed to remove protected file, permission denied?"
   log "Some log message, and somehow append the returned error message from rm"
   exit 1;
}

rm /tmp/protectedfile || quit;
```

Comment: it's better to `exit 1` here... (or whatever >0 integer). Usually you `exit` (or `exit 0`) when the preceding command was OK. and you `exit n` (n= a positive integer, not too huge though) to indicate failure. That allow someone to assign a different positive integer to signal different kind of errors : for example `exit 1` for a "normal" error, `exit 20` for an "outstanding" error, `exit 666` for "fubar" errors, etc...). And in the scripting world, it's what's expected [with, of course, possibly some exceptions...]

Comment: I updated my question with some more information and hopefully clarifies things.

Comment: ok, i'll give an alternative

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want, just use this:

```
rm blah/blah/blah || exit 1
```

Comment: maybe `rm __something__ || exit 1` (or whatever >0 integer), as usually it's what's used to indicate that the preceding command failed (`exit`, or `exit 0`, is usually for success). @gorelative: That will allow you to assign a positive integer to whatever error : for example 1 for normal error, 2 for outstanding error, 3 for "fubar", etc...)

Comment: hmm, actually it's also in the OP's post, i'll comment there as well :/

Comment: @OlivierDulac Good point. I updated my answer. Having a non-success exit code allows for doing the same with his script.

Comment: a simple generic solution: `rm __something__ || exit $?` (which will exit using the same error_code as what the last command (here: rm) returned, when rm returned something >0. And will not exit when rm returned 0.

Comment: It's a bit hard to define the semantics of your return codes then, though. "1 means failure X if command C failed, but failure Y if it was command D that failed... etc". Perhaps better to use the exit code to say which command failed.

Comment: True, but at least it keeps the original error code, whereas always using 1 is ignoring it. In case you just need to test for errors (ie, non-0) (ex: `myscript || { something ;}`, both work. In case you know in later processing that it was an `rm` and that the returned value was the error from that rm, and then proceed in different fashion, my solution will work whereas yours could mislead. (but I agree we are probably in the first case, in which both ways work).

Comment: So this example would allow me to then interpret the rm if it failed, and then i could say.. execute a function i have that writes to a log file, echo's out there was an error and cancels the script from going any further?

Comment: Note that `cmd || exit` is the same as `cmd || exit $?`.  `$?` is the default if no argument is specified to `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

Usualy some would use a command like this:

```
doSomething.sh
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "oops, i did it again"
    exit 1;
fi
```

B.T.W. searching for 'bash exit status' will give you already a lot of good results

Answer (score 0):

a possibility: a 'wrapper' so that you can retrieve the original commands stderr |and stdout?], and maybe also retry it a few times before giving up?, etc.

Here is a version that redirects both stdout and stderr

Of course you could not redirect stdout at all (and usually, you shouldn't, i guess, making the "try_to" function a bit more useful in the rest of the script!)

```
export timescalled=0  #external to the function itself

try_to () {
    let "timescalled += 1"  #let "..." allows white spaces and simple arithmetics
    try_to_out="/tmp/try_to_${$}.${timescalled}" 
        #tries to avoid collisions within same script and/or if multiple script run in parrallel
    zecmd="$1" ; shift ;
    "$1" "$@" 2>"${try_to_out}.ERR" >"${try_to_out}.OUT"
    try_to_ret=$?
    #or: "$1" "$@" >"${try_to_out}.ERR" 2>&1  to have both in the same one
    if [ "$try_to_ret" -ne "0" ]
    then  log "error $try_to_ret while trying to : '${zecmd} $@' ..." "${try_to_out}.ERR" 
            #provides custom error message + the name of the stderr from the command
          rm -f "${try_to_out}.ERR" "${try_to_out}.OUT" #before we exit, better delete this
          exit 1 #or exit $try_to_ret ?
    fi
    rm -f "${try_to_out}.ERR" "${try_to_out}.OUT"
}
```

it's ugly, but could help ^^

note that there are many things that could go wrong: 'timecalled' could become too high, the tmp file(s) could not be writable, zecmd could contain special caracters, etc...